# How to include the docstring for a function from another package in my Julia docs?

Tags: julia

I have a function defined in a different package which I include and then export from my Julia package. I now want to include the docs for that function in my docs using Documenter.jl. What sort of `@ref` syntax would I need to do this? The [documenter docs](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/) don't seem to covet this use case.

Answer (score 4):

That is what we do in `MeasureTheory`, feel free to take a look at https://github.com/cscherrer/MeasureTheory.jl/blob/master/docs/make.jl. Our goal was to include docstrings from `MeasureBase` as well, and all it takes are some tweaks to the `make.jl` file:

- include both packages in the `modules` argument to `makedocs`
- setup doctests for both packages

Note that `MeasureTheory` re-exports `MeasureBase`, otherwise we would need to add `using MeasureBase` at the start of the file too.

Comment: What specifically in the Make.jl file enables the cross package docstrings? It is not clear to me yet.

Comment: It is mostly the fact that we include both packages in the `modules` argument to `makedocs`.There is also some setup related to doctest at the beginning.
Note that `MeasureTheory` reexports `MeasureBase`, otherwise we would need a `using MeasureBase` at the start too.

Comment: Could you update your answer with that information (and maybe link to https://github.com/cscherrer/MeasureTheory.jl/blob/7102906a5336a0aed22456cd3cce673d4ed1fd7e/docs/make.jl#L21)?